# How to scrape url from a html table in python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to scrape the urls from a html table of [this website](https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders.php). I was able to gather **LOCATION | DATE | SUMMARY | DEADLINE**. But the **SUMMARY** field is having a url to another page. I want to scrape the entire table along with this url so my scraped data becomes **LOCATION | DATE | SUMMARY | DEADLINE | URLS**

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders-{}.php'

amount_of_pages = 4796 #5194 
rows = []

for i in range(1,amount_of_pages):
    response = rq.get(url.format(i))


    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table',{'id':'datatable'})

        headers = []

        for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
           headers.append(th.text.strip())

        for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            cells = []
            tds = tr.find_all("td")

            if len(tds) == 0:
                ths = tr.find_all("th")

                for th in ths:
                    cells.append(th.text.strip())
                    links = [th.findAll('a')]
            else:
                for td in tds:
                    cells.append(td.text.strip())
                    links = [td.findAll('a')]

            rows.append(cells)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the '' tag under the `<td>` tag, and pull out the `href` attribute.

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.tendersinfo.com/global-information-technology-tenders-{}.php'

amount_of_pages = 4796 #5194 
rows = []
headers = []

for i in range(1,amount_of_pages+1):  #<-- if theres 4796 pages, your range needs to be to 4797. range goes from (start, end) but the is not inclusive of the end value
    response = rq.get(url.format(i))
    print (i)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table',{'id':'datatable'})

        if len(headers) == 0:
            for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
               headers.append(th.text.strip())
            headers.append('URL')

        for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            cells = []
            tds = tr.find_all("td")

            for td in tds:
                cells.append(td.text.strip())
                if td.find('a'):
                    link = td.find('a')['href']
            cells = cells + [link]        

            rows.append(cells)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, 
               columns =headers)
```